# how do breadcrumbs work?

Tags: yesod

beyond the trivial

`instance YesodBreadcrumbs MySite where
  breadcrumb RootR      = return ("home", Nothing)
  breadcrumb FirstPageR = return ("first page", Just RootR)
  breadcrumb SecondPageR = return ("second page", Just FirstPageR)`

does anyone know how to implement breadcrumbs for situations where a specific page can be reached from several different parents for example?

thanks
konstantin

Comment: Apart from your specific question - this is actually the best sample code I've seen for Yesod breadcrumbs. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies as this isn't a technical answer but more of a UX answer...

> where a specific page can be reached from several different parents for example

If that's the case, then your site's IA isn't conducive to breadcrumb navigation. Showing the same page with two different sets of breadcrumbs will only confuse users. I'd suggest that you instead reference the content in one section of the site from the other rather than duplicate it.

Comment: thank you. my understanding was that breadcrumbs is synonymous with navigation history, that is the breadcrumbs path shows the path that the user used to reach the current page. I do not want to show several different paths in a page. Just one.

Comment: Does OP talk about duplication somewhere? He says "can be reached from several different parents". In my book that's about links, not duplicates.

Comment: "breadcrumbs is synonymous with navigation history" I think originally that was the case and, as a metaphor, certainly makes the most sense. However, most people these days refer to 'breadcrumbs' as being a reflection of the site map/hierarchy rather than a specific path you took. @n.m. if there is no duplication, then there's no need to worry about the breadcrumb issue, hence my assumption that content would be duplicated.

Comment: *if*, on the other hand, you were looking to replicate navigation history, then I'd suggest to not even bother. That's a feature of the web browser. No need to replicate that as part of your site navigation. It was kind of a clever thing to do back in 1999 but doesn't really serve a purpose today.